# Count rows based on first column in a tab delaminated file using Python (without using Pandas, Numpy, etc)

Tags: python

I have a tab delaminated file looks like this:

```
33 1 8
34 1 1
21 1 1
31 1 1
6 1 2
35 1 23
9 1 2
25 1 2
13 2 1
21 2 2
8 2 1
2 2 1
25 2 2
14 2 1
16 2 1
23 2 1
10 2 1
6 2 1
7 2 1
35 2 51
36 2 7
33 2 11
30 2 2
3 2 4
29 2 4
22 3 1
23 3 1
10 3 1
33 3 47
32 3 3
35 3 218
36 3 30
25 3 28
26 3 3
13 3 4
19 3 2
3 3 5
30 3 10
9 3 16
7 3 2
6 3 4
29 3 3
14 3 2
34 3 2
21 3 11
27 3 2
20 3 2
2 3 3
26 4 1
10 4 1
2 4 1
```

There are over 10000 rows in this file, I want to use the first column as key, for example, the first row, 33 is the key,  and then print out the count of rows that first column is 33 in the output file.

```
key,count
33,490
34,670
21,300
31,675
6,700
8,90
.
.
.
```

There should be 36 keys in the output file.

Below is my code so far

```
import csv

# Create dictionary to hold the data
valDic = {}
Count = 0


# Read data into dictionary
with open('matrix.mtx', 'r',) as inputfile:

    reader = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter = '\t')
    next(reader)

    for row in reader:
        key = row[0]
        if key in valDic:
            valDic[key] +=1
            Count += 1




#Prepare new CSV
newcsvfile = [["ADT", "Count"]] 

for key, Count in sorted(valDic.items()):
    newcsvfile.append([valDic[key], Count])

with open('results5.csv', "w", newline='') as outputfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outputfile)
    writer.writerows(newcsvfile)
```

Comment: post your efforts

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Code updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('data.txt') as i, open('output.csv', 'w') as o:

    counts = Counter(key for key, *_ in map(str.split, i))  # split by space and get first element 

    w = csv.writer(o)
    w.writerow(['key', 'count'])  # write header
    for item in counts.items():
        w.writerow(item)
```

**Output** *(partial)*

```
key,count
33,3
34,2
21,3
31,1
6,3
35,3
9,2
25,3
13,2
8,1
2,3
14,2
```

Notice that the partial output is for input sample. The notation in the counting and splitting line is known as [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), an alternative way of writing is:

```
counts = Counter(splits[0] for splits in map(str.split, i))
```

**Update**

If you want the output sorted in ascending order, change the writing logic to:

```
w = csv.writer(o)
w.writerow(['key', 'count'])  # write header
for item in sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0])):
    w.writerow(item)
```

Comment: It works, And I want the file sorted based on Key in increasing order

Comment: @WendyHuang Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Say that your file is called `data.txt`, you can load it into a `pandas` DataFrame and then group by the first column

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', delimiter='\t', names=['key', 'a', 'b'])

df.groupby('key').size().reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I don't want to use pandas or Numpy, etc